# Java String exponents

Tags: java, string, exponent

How would I calculate `String number = "3^6"`?
There are math options to calculate exponents but how would I convert a string into something that the java math class can solve?

Comment: Is it always in this exact form or are you looking to handle arbitrarily complex equations? Have you attempted writing code which you could share for help with?

Comment: FInd the exponent sign in the string using indexOf(), take out the parts before and after it using substring(), convert them to numbers using Integer.parseInt(), then call Math.pow().

Comment: For the general problem of calculating mathematical expressions, see for example JEP: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/

Comment: If you're going to take the time to do that then why not write a program to convert algebraic expressions into post fix (RPN) notation and then evaluate them.

Comment: I have used the shunting yard algorithm, but that doesn't mean it knows how to solve exponents. So yea, they are already RPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out if you'd like to have a generic expression evaluation:

```java
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Main {

  static ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
  static ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("mvel");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    System.out.println(eval("3^6"));
    System.out.println(eval("(1+2)^(2*3)"));
    System.out.println(eval("2^2^2"));
  }

  private static Number eval(String expression) throws ScriptException {
    int idx = expression.indexOf('^');
    if (idx > 0) {
      String left = expression.substring(0, idx);
      String right = expression.substring(idx + 1);
      double base = eval(left).doubleValue();
      double exp = eval(right).doubleValue();
      return Math.pow(base, exp);
    }

    return (Number) engine.eval(expression);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
729.0
729.0
16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "3^6";
String[] sArr = s.split("\\^");
double[] dArr = {Double.valueOf(sArr[0]), Double.valueOf(sArr[1])};
System.out.println(Math.pow(dArr[0], dArr[1]));
```

This should get you started. Prints:

```
729.0
```

Of course, with complex equations, you will have to write the code to handle it accordingly.

If your equations have brackets, you a `Stack` to check the opening and closing brackets. And if the equation is something like: `3 ^ 6 ^ 2`, calculate the exponents in a loop.